# The longest word without A,E,I,O, or U

Tags: word

**SPY** and **SKY** are examples of words without any true vowel in it.
(I am referring to **A**, **E**, **I**, **O**, **U** as vowels.)

> **Question:** What is longest English word that has no vowel in it. (Please post its meaning as well)

(Note: No googling allowed, at least give it a try with your knowledge)

Please do not downvote anymore... I just tried to create a puzzle.

Comment: According to Oxford and dictionary.com, y is a vowel in these contexts.

Comment: @ Ian MacDonald vowel sound is allowed but no vowel letter allowed

Comment: The word "vowel" and "consonant" are specifically related to the sound. There is no such thing as a "vowel sound" that is not also a "vowel letter". [Go read it yourself on dictionary.com.](http://dictionary.reference.com/help/faq/language/g01.html)

Comment: Yep for that sake i have edited my question..:P

Comment: This puzzle reminded me of "SHY GYPSY SLYLY SPRYLY TRYST BY MY CRYPT" from the 7th Guest.

Comment: please do not down vote any more. I just tried to create a good puzzle :(

Comment: I don't get why this puzzle is so down-rated.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Depending on what you mean by vowels, the max length can be **7** or **12**

If you consider (w,y) vowels, I have one of 7 letters!

> **Tsktsks**

Which is the 3rd person of this verb:

> [Tsktsk]

Meaning:

> To make a tsktsk sound of disapproval.

This contains no vowel nor sounds like vowels (y,w)!
This is present in Wikipedia [here](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tsktsk) and dictionary.reference [here](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/tsktsk)

If you also accept the sounds y and w, then the answer is

> **twyndyllyngs**

which has 12 letters!!! Confirmed [here](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/twyndyllyng)

Comment: Correct.... but see @GentlePurpleRain answer as well.Actually that is what was in my mind.

Comment: @user2408578 I guess you accepted his answer too early, because I've just found a 12 letters word!

Comment: @user2408578 Have you considered the possibility of "what was in your mind" not being the correct answer to the puzzle you posted?

Comment: Twyndyllyngs is the answer that Guinness World Records accepted.

Comment: yes tomorrow may be another word would come up with more than this letter....:P.So for now i have accepted this answer.Previous rolled back

Answer (score 6):

Going just by memory, I would say:

> syzygy (when 3 astronomical objects are in a line)

I remember that from a previous puzzle here.

Comment: the word that i know has same number of characters as yours so may be if that wont came up ill accept this as answer.Also please provide meaning as well if possible.

Comment: This is the one I first thought of (but forgot how to spell exactly) :) lol

Answer (score 5):

The first thing I thought of was

> Rhythms

Comment: Nice 7-letter word!

Comment: That's what is i was looking for....Great :)

Comment: Rhythm / Rhythms

Comment: What's wrong with twyndyllyng?

Comment: @leoll2 Gesundheit

Answer (score 3):

**[crwth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crwth)**

That would work if you're going with the "A, E, I, O, U, and sometimes Y" definition. Though you'd probably call "w" a vowel in this context.

Comment: Need to post meaning as well for others.+1 for serious attempt.And vowel sound is allowed but letter not allowed

Comment: The word is a link to the Wikipedia article.

Answer (score 2):

I was always taught that

> nth

was the only/longest word without vowels (w and y included) but i did not think about leoll2's answer

Answer (score 1):

I can at least tie pacoverflow's answer, with:

> crypts, which loosely can be defined as "cellars or underground vaults".

Answer (score 1):

> **NYMPHS , GLYPHS**

Most of the words need Y, I guess, as it makes up for a good substitute to vowels.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of a 7 letter word

> nymphly

Answer (score 1):

The [regexp dictionary](http://www.visca.com/regexdict/) says the full list of vowel-less words (by their definition of a 'word') is:

> -'s
>   -cy
>   -fy
>   -gyny
>   -phyll
>   -ry
>   -st
>   -ty
>   -yl
>   24-7
>   3-D
>   b
>   bb
>   by
>   by-
>   c
>   cd
>   chrys-
>   cry
>   crypt
>   crypt-
>   cycl-
>   Cymry
>   cyst
>   cyst-
>   cyt-
>   d
>   dj
>   dry
>   dys-
>   f
>   fly
>   flyby
>   fry
>   ft-c
>   ft-lb
>   g
>   glyc-
>   glyph
>   gym
>   gyn-
>   gyp
>   Gypsy
>   h
>   hydr-
>   hymn
>   hyp-
>   hypn-
>   j
>   k 
>   l
>   lymph
>   lymph-
>   lynch
>   lynx
>   lys-
>   m
>   my
>   my-
>   myc-
>   myrrh
>   myth
>   myx-
>   n
>   nth
>   nymph
>   p
>   pfft
>   phyll-
>   phys-
>   ply
>   pry
>   psst
>   psych
>   psych-
>   py-
>   Pygmy
>   pyr-
>   pyx
>   q
>   r
>   rhythm
>   s
>   scry
>   shy
>   sky
>   sly
>   spry
>   spy
>   sty
>   styl-
>   Styx
>   sylph
>   sym-
>   syn-
>   sync
>   synch
>   synth
>   syzygy
>   t
>   thy
>   try
>   tryst
>   tsk
>   tyyn
>   v
>   w
>   why
>   wry
>   wynn
>   x
>   xyl-
>   y
>   z

This doesn't include plurals - if you pluralise the nouns then rhythms  wins out over syzygy.

Answer (score 1):

There is even a rock band without a vowel:

> **Lynyrd Skynyrd**

It does not appear in the Oxford Online Dictionary, but it is recognised by many people. The origin of the name is (From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_band_name_etymologies))

> After Leonard Skinner, a gym teacher at Robert E. Lee High School in Jacksonville, Florida who was notorious for strictly enforcing the school's policy against boys having long hair.